# Why javascript 'if else' statement seems looping over

Tags: javascript

I am writing some javascript code called account register. The requirement is showing information inputted on the screen when clicked the register button, and each row can be deleted by clicking the delete button on the left.

My problem is when the first time I click the register button, information not showing up. The second time is fine. From the third time, extra rows start added. For me it seems the 'if else' statement is looping over inside the function.

What is the reason of that?

[Execute result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx10L.png)

```js
var counterVal = 0;

document.getElementById("tuikaBtn").onclick = function() {
  const addButton = document.getElementById('tuikaBtn');
  const listContainer = document.getElementById('result');
  const name = document.getElementById('namae');
  const nick = document.getElementById('nickname');
  const rmvButton = document.getElementById('rmv');

  console.log('counter = ' + counterVal);

  if (name.value == "" | nick.value == "") {
    window.alert("Please input both name and nickname.");
  } else if (counterVal == 3) {
    document.getElementById("tuikaBtn").style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    //funtion to get parent item
    const handleRemove = function(e) {
      const item = e.target.closest('.item');

      //remove the listener, to avoid memory leaks.
      item.querySelector('.remove-btn').removeEventListener('click', handleRemove);
      item.parentElement.removeChild(item);
    };

    //adds text and button to list once clicked the button
    addButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const item = document.createElement('div');
      const paragraph = document.createElement('div');
      const remove = document.createElement('button');

      item.classList.add('item');
      paragraph.classList.add('paragraph-style');
      remove.classList.add('remove-btn');

      paragraph.textContent = name.value + ' ' + nick.value;
      remove.textContent = 'Remove';

      item.append(paragraph);
      item.append(remove);
      listContainer.append(item);

      name.value = '';
      nick.value = '';

      remove.addEventListener('click', handleRemove);
    })

    return counterVal += 1;
  }
}
```

```css
.base {
  margin: 2% 7% 0;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  padding: 5% 10%;
  box-shadow: 5px 9px 8px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

input {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: large;
}

#tuikaBtn {
  background: green;
}

h1 {
  font-family: serif;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
  color: #cacaca;
  opacity: 1;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #312929;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

.back {
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.form-group {
  margin: 10px 0 15px 0px;
}

#result {
  font-size: 120%;
  margin: 10;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  padding: 10px 5px 20px;
  margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.row .card {
  color: black;
}

.card {
  color: blue;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#modal {
  display: none;
  margin: 1.5em auto 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#overLay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.items {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 6em;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.667em;
  align-items: center;
}

.paragraph-style {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="base container">

  <div class="row">
    <h1>Account Register</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="card" id="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <form id="form-area" class="form-inline" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input id="namae" name="namae" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input id="nickname" name="nickname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nick Name">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="tuikaBtn" type="button" name="touroku" value="Add">
          </div>
        </form>

        <div id="tuikaMoto">User Information</div>
        <div id="result"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="overLay"></div>
```

Comment: If you can provide code as Code Sample and in different files it would be way more understandable for us

Comment: Generally adding/removing event listeners inside the results of an event listener is a bad idea and gets very messy.

Comment: Should it not be || rather than | in `if (name.value == "" | nick.value == "")`?

Comment: [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) is `||` not `|`. `|` is [Bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR).

Comment: You set `tuikaBtn.onclick` twice. Only after the first click is it then set to the code you want.

Comment: @MariusROBERT Thank you for the recommendation. Will do so next.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you for the comment. I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one tuikaBtn.onclick is needed. Also no need of counter

```js
document.getElementById("tuikaBtn").onclick = function() {
  const listContainer = document.getElementById('result');
  const name = document.getElementById('namae');
  const nick = document.getElementById('nickname');
  const rmvButton = document.getElementById('rmv');

  if (name.value == "" || nick.value == "") {
    window.alert("Please input both name and nickname.");
  } 
  else {
    //funtion to get parent item
    const handleRemove = function(e) {
      const item = e.target.closest('.item');

      //remove the listener, to avoid memory leaks.
      item.querySelector('.remove-btn').removeEventListener('click', handleRemove);
      item.parentElement.removeChild(item);
      document.getElementById("tuikaBtn").style.display = '';
    };

    //adds text and button to list once clicked the button
   ////// addButton.addEventListener('click', e => {    /// // /no need of this 
      const item = document.createElement('div');
      const paragraph = document.createElement('div');
      const remove = document.createElement('button');

      item.classList.add('item');
      paragraph.classList.add('paragraph-style');
      remove.classList.add('remove-btn');

      paragraph.textContent = name.value + ' ' + nick.value;
      remove.textContent = 'Remove';

      item.append(paragraph);
      item.append(remove);
      listContainer.append(item);

      name.value = '';
      nick.value = '';

      remove.addEventListener('click', handleRemove);
      if(listContainer.querySelectorAll('.item').length>=3)
      {
        document.getElementById("tuikaBtn").style.display = 'none';
      }else{
        document.getElementById("tuikaBtn").style.display = '';
      }
 //////   })
  }
}
```

```css
.base {
  margin: 2% 7% 0;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  padding: 5% 10%;
  box-shadow: 5px 9px 8px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

input {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: large;
}

#tuikaBtn {
  background: green;
}

h1 {
  font-family: serif;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
  color: #cacaca;
  opacity: 1;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #312929;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

.back {
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.form-group {
  margin: 10px 0 15px 0px;
}

#result {
  font-size: 120%;
  margin: 10;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  padding: 10px 5px 20px;
  margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.row .card {
  color: black;
}

.card {
  color: blue;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#modal {
  display: none;
  margin: 1.5em auto 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#overLay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.items {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 6em;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.667em;
  align-items: center;
}

.paragraph-style {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="base container">

  <div class="row">
    <h1>Account Register</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="card" id="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <form id="form-area" class="form-inline" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input id="namae" name="namae" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input id="nickname" name="nickname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nick Name">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="tuikaBtn" type="button" name="touroku" value="Add">
          </div>
        </form>

        <div id="tuikaMoto">User Information</div>
        <div id="result"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="overLay"></div>
```